# How can we sort "Reviews" by date returned from Product Advertising API?

Tags: review, amazon-advertising-api

I'm  using Product Advertising API for fetch product reviews by ASIN. Its good. But can we sort **product reviews** by "**Date**".
Because I want to display **latest review** on the top. Is that possible?
Can anybody  help me, I stuck here from last few days.

Thanks,
Surinder

Answer (score -1):

This type of call will get top reviews, including some recent.

https://www.amazon.com/reviews/iframe?akid=[AWSAccessKeyId]&alinkCode=xm2&asin=[ASIN]&atag=[ASSOCIATE_TAG]&exp=[DATE]&summary=1&truncate=1000&v=2&sig=[SIGNATURE]

You can experiment with different flags for possible sorting, however Amazon's API document does not detail sort specific parameters:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_RetrievingCustomerReviews.html